# Uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(r-z)^2}$ in a neighborhood

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to show that the function $f(z)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(r-z)^2}$ defined on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is holomorphic *assuming* that the series  $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(r-z)^2}$ is uniformly convergent in some neighborhood of $z$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{N}$

I answered this using Morera's Theorem, but I couldn't show (and couldn't *'see'* how this is true) how the series was uniformly convergent in some neighborhood. It isn't part of the question, but it's just that I'm not satisfied with assuming it (it doesnt look clear to me)

I guess I have to use M-test but I had troubles finding a suitable upper bound for $f_n(z) = \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(r-z)^2}$.

Basically I have no idea after that. It would be nice if someone could give me (not necessarily fully rigourous) a short proof or insight into this. I'd love if it contains relatively basic maths in it, since otherwise I might not understand.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you first fix $z$ and some neighbourhood of it, and then find suitable bounds for $\frac{1}{(r-z)^2}$ *for sufficiently large* $r$.

Consider an arbitrary $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{N}$. Then there is an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lvert z\rvert < n-1$.

Now we show that the series is uniformly convergent on $K = \{ w\in \mathbb{C} : \lvert w\rvert \leqslant n\}\setminus \mathbb{N}$.

For $r \geqslant 2n$ and $w\in K$, we have $\lvert w\rvert \leqslant n \leqslant \frac{r}{2}$, and therefore $\lvert r-w\rvert \geqslant r - \lvert w\rvert \geqslant r - \frac{r}{2} = \frac{r}{2}$. That gives us

$$\left\lvert\frac{1}{(r-w)^2}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{(r-\lvert w\rvert)^2} \leqslant \frac{4}{r^2}.$$

Since $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{r^2} < \infty$, the Weierstraß $M$-test tells us that the series

$$\sum_{r=2n}^\infty \frac{1}{(r-z)^2}$$

is uniformly convergent on $K$. The uniform convergence is not influenced by adding the finite sum

$$\sum_{r < 2n} \frac{1}{(r-z)^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a much stronger result than what I'd expected! Silly me, I couldn't come up with reverse triangle inequaility :P

Answer (score 1):

For $z\not\in\mathbb{N}$, take $\epsilon>0$ such that every $w$ with $|w-z|<\epsilon$ is also not in $\mathbb{N}$. Fix such a $w$.

Now, let $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $M>|z|+\epsilon$.

$$g(w)=\sum_{n=0}^M\frac{1}{(n-w)^n}$$
is a holomorphic function, because it is a finite sum. Now, if $n>M$, we have that
$$|w-n|^2\geq (n-M)^2$$
so
$$\frac{1}{|w-n|^2}\leq\frac{1}{(n-M)^2}\;.$$
Therefore, the series
$$\sum_{n=M+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(w-n)^2}$$
converges uniformly for $|z-w|<\epsilon$, by comparison with $\sum 1/k^2$.